# Can't open Camera using Intent in landscape orientation

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on Android application that capture images and upload this images to a server.
I used intent to open the camera:

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

I need to open the camera in landscape orientation, I tried this approach and nothing changed

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

Any advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the camera app is up to the developers of the camera app. There are hundreds of camera apps, both pre-installed and user-installed. `EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION` is not documented as being part of the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol, and I am not aware of any camera apps that would honor it. There is no requirement for *any* camera app to let callers force a screen orientation.

You could integrate a camera library (CameraX from Google, etc.) and take photos yourself directly in your app. Then, you would be able to control the orientation of your screen (e.g., via `android:screenOrientation` in the manifest).